# ¿Cómo hacer para que borre mi TextView al seleccionar la posicion 0 de mi Spinner

Tags: java, android

Uso un `Spinner` que según la *posición* que seleccione manda un texto u otro a `TextView`, tengo programado que compruebe si el `TextView` está vacío para no dejar continuar y te mande un *Toast* pero al seleccionar otra *posición* que no sea la 0 y luego volver a ella, `TextView` queda relleno por lo tanto al comprobar lo encuentra relleno con lo que le ha mandado la otra *posición* y me deja continuar en la posición 0, por eso necesito que cada vez que seleccione la *posición* 0 esta borre el `TextView`

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == 1){
            TextView.setText(" ");
        }else if(position !=0){
            String description = zodiaco[position];
            TextView.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
        }
        //Se mueve a la posición seleccionada.
        spin.setSelection(position);
    }
```

Comment: Simplemente cambia el `position == 1` por `position == 0`, y no sé como será tu comprobación de `TextView` vacío, pero en el ´setText´ estás colocando un espacio: `" "` y no cadena vacía: `""`

Comment: No, si hago eso me dejaría avanzar incluso en posición 0, necesito que borre mi `TextView` @cnbandicoot está así para que escriba ahí si selecciono otra posición que no sea la 0

Comment: comparto lo de setText("")... oye, pero la posición 0 es seleccionable? si es así deberías solo cambiar 'posición == 0'

Comment: A ver, posición 0 **no** es seleccionable, pero si selecciono otra posición mi `TextView` queda relleno y si vuelvo a posición 0 ya me deja avanzar porque no borra mi `TextView` la posición 1 si es seleccionable pero manda un texto vacío, y está bien, y en la posición 0 está así " " porque si seleccionas otra posición ahí envía el texto. El problema es que quiero que borre mi `TextView` siempre que seleccione la posición 0 @Maguz

Comment: Entonces ¿como puedes volver a la posicion 0, si según tu no es seleccionable? Añade el resto del código en el que "compruebas" que esté relleno, para que te deje avanzar.

Comment: Ahí me he explicado mal, es seleccionable pero como no manda texto, no te deja continuar, pero al seleccionar otra posicion si manda texto y al volver a 0 necesito que borre `TexView` para que no este el texto que mando la otra posicion @cnbandicoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi respuesta sería la siguiente:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        TextView.setText("");
    } else if (position == 1) {
        TextView.setText(" ");
    } else {
        String description = zodiaco[position];
        TextView.setText(description.split(" ")[0]);
    }

    spin.setSelection(position);
}
```

Donde tu método para comprobar los datos sería algo así:

```
public boolean datosValidos() {
    if (TextView.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Campo vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Llamándolo así:

```
if (datosValidos()) {
    //hacer lo que sea
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! El método de comprobar y llamar lo tenía correctamente, gracias por la solución, marco como útil y +1 ! @cnbandicoot